# VSCode: The 'workbench.colorCustomizations' takes no effect to set the theme of the terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I added these lines to the 'settings.json', the theme of the terminal did not change.

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "terminal.background":"#282B35",
  "terminal.foreground":"#939599",
  "terminalCursor.background":"#939599",
  "terminalCursor.foreground":"#939599",
  "terminal.ansiBlack":"#282B35",
  "terminal.ansiBlue":"#790EAD",
  "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#686A71",
  "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#790EAD",
  "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#00A0BE",
  "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#DF0002",
  "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#B21889",
  "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#B21889",
  "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#BEBFC2",
  "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#438288",
  "terminal.ansiCyan":"#00A0BE",
  "terminal.ansiGreen":"#DF0002",
  "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#B21889",s
  "terminal.ansiRed":"#B21889",
  "terminal.ansiWhite":"#939599",
  "terminal.ansiYellow":"#438288"
}
```

However, other settings not about the terminal will work correctly, such as the following line.

```
"activityBar.background": "#00AA00"
```

So, what is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The settings in VSCode are separated into 2 environments. The user's setting and the workspace's setting, basically the workspace's setting would overwrite the user's setting. Maybe the terminal's colors are overwritten inside the workspace setting.

- The Workspace setting is located inside `.vscode` folder: `.vscode\settings.json`